# losing values when converting Array<Int> to IntArray in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I initialized two dimensional array of int like this below

```
var array = Array(n) { Array(n) { 0 } }
```

then I did some logic on `array` to populate values.

when it comes to converting Row values of `array` (so `Array<Int>` type) to `IntArray` type using `.toIntArray()`, it behaves differently depending on how to execute corresponding function calls.(`toIntArray()` and `contentToString()`)
Please look at this screenshot that I ran on XXX.kts scratch file on Android Studio.
[image]

`test2` results in values back to 0s. `test` keeps populated values with the logic performed as I mentioned earlier.

I can not figure out what is going on here.

I will appreciate

1. if you could explain why same functions call but different way of calling them results in different outputs.
2. if you could suggest a way to convert `Array<Int>` to `IntArray` (maybe in two dimensional array specifically I guess)

[UPDATE]
Sorry that I didn't attach logic part of code.
The code is like this.(I changed a logic part but it is almost identical. Logic is basically assigning integers in the array.)

```
for (i in 0..5) {
    for (j in 0..5) {
        array[i][j] = i + j
    }
}

val test = array[0]
println(test.contentToString())
val test2 = test.toIntArray()
println(test.toIntArray().contentToString())
println(test2.contentToString())
```

and the screenshot with the code look like this below.[image]

[UPDATE 2]
just to be clear for running the code, make sure to initialize `n` to be specific number at the very beginning before initializing `array`. so it should be something like this.

```
val n = 6
var array = Array(n) { Array(n) { 0 } }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Also, post the code as *text* please.

Comment: `test.contentToString()` *cannot be* `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` with just the code you showed. "then I did some logic on array to populate values" - Please show "some logic".

Comment: I updated my question with full code. I will appreciate if you could test the code that I attached and see the same result that I have on Android Studio Scratch file.
I never redefined any function. That code is entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this in the scratch, but it works fine in a main that I run as a Kotlin application. I think there must be a bug in the interactive mode used in IntelliJ. (It works fine when "Use REPL" is checked)

This gives the bad behavior:

```kotlin
var n = 0

val array = Array(6) { Array(6) { 0 } }
for (i in 0..5) {
    for (j in 0..5) {
        array[i][j] = i + j
    }
}

val test = array[0]
println(test.contentToString())
val test2 = test.toIntArray()
println(test.toIntArray().contentToString())
println(test2.contentToString())
```

I've filed [a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-331227/Interactive-Mode-for-scratch.kts-gives-odd-results-for-toIntArray) for IntelliJ.

This seems related to [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-13511/Scratch-wrong-variable-initialization-value-computed-from-reassigned-variable) which demonstrates a simpler case (which I just tested and shows the incorrect value of `10`):

```kotlin
// code from related bug report
var a = 10
a = 20
val t = a
t // prints 10, but 20 is expected
```

The related bug was filed four years ago and the last comment was from 2022. I voted for it, and hopefully the new bug will cause someone to look at the issue again.

Comment: I filed bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-331227/Interactive-Mode-for-scratch.kts-gives-odd-results-for-toIntArray - looks like it may be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-13511/Scratch-wrong-variable-initialization-value-computed-from-reassigned-variable, which shows a simpler case. I just tested their simpler case and it has the same issue.